# Redirecting a custom domain to a specific tumblr page, rather than the blog

Tags: javascript, redirect

Hoping I can get some help on this one. I'm looking into redirecting a domain to a specific tumblr page, rather than to the main blog, to act as a static landing page. I've managed to find the javascript to redirect like in this case:

```
if(location.href == 'http://example.tumblr.com/') location.replace('http://example.tumblr.com/about');;
```

But this means that I can't get back to the main blog, as it constantly redirects back to the landing page. Any way that I can have both worlds? It would be nice to do this for my own site as well. A quick search on here hasn't found this specific issue, at least so far.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is when the user goes to your blog he's redirected to another page and when you go there using a link on the blog he isn't redirected? If you are, add a `#` to the link to the homepage. Because `"http://example.tumblr.com/#"` does not equal `"http://example.tumblr.com/"`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanna redirect the user to a certain page if he/she comes from another domain. You can use this, this'll check the referrer page and make a redirect accordingly.

```
if(!/http:\/\/(www\.)?YOUR_DOMAIN\.com/.test(document.referrer)) {
  window.location = "http://example.tumblr.com/about";
}
```